# -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done' in script

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I am sorry for posting this but this is driving me crazy. I am very new to bash scripting and am really struggling. I have files with the following format 8_S58_L001.sorted.bam and I would like to take the first digit (8 in this case) from many files and generate a csv file. This will give me the order in which samples were processed by a downstream function.
The script is as follows and it works, however I get an error (-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done') everytime I run it and am struggling to understand why. So far I have spent 2 days trying to get to the bottom  of it and have searched extensively through various forums.

```
do
test=$(ls -LR | grep .bam$| sed 's/_.*//'| awk '{print}' ORS=',' | sed 's/*$//')
echo $test>../SampleOrder/fileOrder2.csv
done
```

If I just run

```
test=$(ls -LR | grep .bam$| sed 's/_.*//'| awk '{print}' ORS=',' | sed 's/*$//')
echo $test>../SampleOrder/fileOrder2.csv
```

Then I get the desired output and no errors but if it is incorporated within an do statement I get the above error. I am hoping to incorporate this into a larger script so I want to deal with this error first.

I should say that this is being run on a linux based cluster.

Can someone with more experience tell me where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance

Sam

Comment: `do` is used for loops. Why do you feel you need to put it in a `do` statement without a loop?

Comment: There is no `do` statement just like there's no `then` statement. There's a `for` statement, and a `while` statement that both include the word `do` as part of their syntax just like the `if` statement used `then`. Also you do not need grep and/or sed if you are using awk since awk can do anything they can do and you should be doing `ls *.bam` not `ls | grep bam`. Finally you need to quote your variables. Not to be rude but every statement in your script is wrong in some way. If you post some sample input and expected output we can put you on the right path.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I think I have got to the bottom of the problem thanks to rici. I have been staring at this code for so long that I failed to realize that there is no actual loop needed and therefore do and done can be omitted and it works fine. This is my first attempt at bash scripting. It may not be the most elegant solution but it actually works (I am a biologist not a programmer)! It is supposed to take list of files format 8_S58_L001.sorted.bam take the first number and output a single csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bash doesn't have a `do` statement, and `done` is a reserved word when it is the first word in a command.

So in

```
do
  something
  something
done
```

`do` is a syntax error. `do` is only useful in the context of `for` and `while` loops, where it serves to separate the condition from the body of the loop.

Since you're reporting a syntax error on the `done` as opposed to the `do`, my guess is that you've let Windows line-endings creep into your file. Bash doesn't regard the `\r` (<kbd>CR</kbd>) character as special, so if your file actually contains `do\r`, then that will be considered to be the name of an external command.

Comment: rici, thanks for your reply. I have been working on processing my data by adapting other scripts that I have found online. Many of them seem to have do and done statements in them but what you are saying is that there is nothing wrong with this script as is and I can simply remove the do and done in this case. Thanks

Comment: @Sam: `while condition; do ... done` is a statement. `do ... done` is not.

Comment: Ok I think I get it now. The other scripts have do as part of a for loop. As you may have guessed I am a biologist and not a programmer. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that `grep .bam$` doesn't do what you are expecting it to do. The dot is a grep wildcard which matches any single character, so the pattern `.bam$` will match any string of 4 or more characters that ends in "bam". If you are trying to match all strings that end in ".bam", you should escape the dot and write `grep "\.bam$"`

But as a previous commenter correctly noted, you should be using shell wildcards (`ls *.bam`) instead of grep (`ls | grep .bam$`)